# unable to launch docker while creating instance with terraform script

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, terraform, devops, user-data

Following is .tf script

```
resource "aws_instance" "zk" {
  ami           = var.ami_id_zk
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  count         = "1"
  vpc_security_group_ids=[aws_security_group.allow_ssh.id]
  key_name = var.key_name
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.public_1.id
  tags = {
    Name = "Zookeper"
  user_data = file("test.sh")
  }
 }
```

This is a terraform file and in user_data = file("test.sh") the test sh looks like this

```
#! /bin/sh

sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt install docker.io -y
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo systemctl enable docker
```

Expected result : it should launch a instance with docker already installed , but unfortunately every time I run the script docker is not getting installed and I have to do it manually

Can anybody help me where I am lacking ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `user_data` is **inside the tags**:

```
  tags = {
    Name = "Zookeper"
  user_data = file("test.sh")
  }
```

It should be outside:

```
resource "aws_instance" "zk" {
  ami           = var.ami_id_zk
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  count         = "1"
  vpc_security_group_ids=[aws_security_group.allow_ssh.id]
  key_name = var.key_name
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.public_1.id

  user_data = file("test.sh")

  tags = {
    Name = "Zookeper"
  }
 }
```